# Is there any exist API for URL-encoding in mfc c++?

Tags: c++, api, mfc, atl, url-encoding

I am using the following code:

```
CAtlNavigateData navData;
CStringA m_strForm = "name=+++&priv=1&password="；
navData.SetPostData((BYTE*)(LPSTR)(LPCSTR)m_strForm, m_strForm.GetLength(), QHTTP_FORM_URLENCODE);
```

special symbols such as :"+++" need to do url-encoding, without url-encoding, +++ will turned into space.

I need a converer.

```
CString URLEncodingConvertion(const CString& original)
{
XXX
}
```

Is there any APIs for doing this in c++? 
If I implement it myself, maybe I can not take whole situations into account. And can not control the code.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`AtlEscapeUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa648e15%28VS.80%29.aspx)